# Angular Observables, subscribing to multiple http requests, no chaining

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, angular2-observables

I'm looking for some help regarding Observables with Angular.

```
export class Car implements OnInit {
    exterior: Exterior;
    engine: Engine;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getContent();
    }

    getContent() {
        this.exterior.getContent();
        this.engine.getContent();
    }
}

export class Exterior {
    color: string;
    doors: number;

    getContent() {
        this.http.get('url').map((response) => {
            this.color = response.color;
            this.doors = response.doors;
        });
    }
}

export class Engine {
    horsePower: number;
    model: string;

    getContent() {
        this.http.get('url').map((response) => {
            this.horsePower = response.horsePower;
            this.doors = response.doors;
        });
    }
}

const car = new Car();
console.log(car);
```

So, I have these 3 objects, and what I want is that when I call new Car() it fills in the parameters. Then I want to `log` this car object after all the http requests are made, which means that both `getContents` of `Exterior` and `Engine` have been completed which would mean that `getContents` of `Car` has been completed, and finally `ngOnInit`. I do not wish to chain these http requests, meaning only calling the second http request after the first one was completed. Both should go out at the same time.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RxJs you should try something like this :

```
    export class Car implements OnInit {

        exterior: Exterior;
        engine: Engine;

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getContent();
        }

        getContent(): Observable<any> {

           return forkJoin(this.exterior.getContent(), this.engine.getContent());

          }
    }
```

Inside other component:

```
...
this.car.getContent().subscribe(
              results => {
                 let exterior = result[0];
                 let engine = result[1];
                 // Do whatever you want here
              });
          )
...
```

It also implies that your `exterior.getContent()` and `engine.getContent()` methods should both return an Observable of the data you want to use

Comment: ok but I want to listen from another component, meaning getContent of Car should return observable.

ngOnInit returns void, so I have to call getContent from the other component, but how do I make getContent return an observable?

Comment: I updated my first post, just return the forkJoin result and subscribe it when and where you want :)